# Make google.com my default search engine

Tags: google-chrome, redirection, google-search

I am really upset by the fact that when I enter something in address bar the google redirects me to google.bg ".bg" is Bulgaria domain extension. 
What I want is my chrome language to be English and google.com to be the default url. Even when I type google.com it redirects me to google.bg which really ruffles my feathers! Please give me some help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Goto `Chrome`settings > `Manage search engines` and add new search engine.
Give this address for new engine `https://www.google.com/search?q=%s&gl=us&gws_rd=cr` and make it default search engine. It will tell Google to not use Country redirection.

This solution is from http://www.thesempost.com/force-google-chrome-to-use-google-com-not-country-version/ where the process is explained like this:

> But in Chrome, even if the default search engine is set as Google.com, it will still automatically route the searcher to the Google version for the country they are in, requiring users to go back to Google.com and click the “Go to Google.com” link that appears in the homepage footer.
>
> There is a way to set Google.com as the default in Chrome, for marketers wishing to keep an eye on the Google.com search results instead of their own country version.
>
> First, in Chrome, go to settings then click “Manage search engines”, even if it currently shows Google as the default.
>
> Then scroll all the way to the bottom until you see the “Add a new search engine” box.
>
> For search engine name, type “Google NCR” and for keyword type “Google NCR_” – this will serve to remind you that this is the Google search with “No Country Redirect” enabled, although you can name it whatever you’d like.  I’d avoid naming it just “Google” to prevent confusion.
>
> Then, in the URL field, enter:

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=%s&gl=us&gws_rd=cr
```

> Be sure it is exactly as above, including all parameters.   Add it, save as default search engine, then set this new Google NCR as the default search engine.
>
> Now when you search with Google Chrome using the address/search bar, it will always search using Google.com without the country redirect.
>
> Do note that your local search results may be skewed by using Google.com although the AdWords ads displayed will still be geotargeted to your location, which is working as intended.  If you want to see AdWords ads for another country, you would need to use a proxy or VPN to do so.

Comment: You should quote the relevant information from your link.

Comment: I tough I had already quoted all relevant parts. Now I have quoted everyting even remotely relevant to the problem.

Comment: In the original revision of this answer, you quoted nothing, you stated something which I assume was your own words then provided a link.  You act like citing material and quoting such material, is a huge request, it really isn't.  **Plagiarism is a big deal.**

Comment: I was under impression that summarising relevant information and giving source to it is 100% legal is case like this. If that is not case I will change the way I give credit. Also I am not concidering anything "huge deal" I was just confused because I did not understand details of the problem from your first (very short) comment. Your second comment helped, now I understand what you meant. And certainly was not trying to steal credit of this solution.

Comment: You are encouraged to summarize information but unless something is 100% your own words, you should also cite the source material that you based your summation on otherwise what is the point of providing the link?  The reason I asked you to quote the information is so, the linked website can go down, but we will always have the information here.  You would be shocked at how many people have a problem with quoting supplying the relevant information from a link, they flat out refuse to do it, so my reaction to your comment was based on those experiences.

Comment: I still can't believe there is a stupid button in chrome settings to do this, great answer.